# Tensorflow scan temporal taps

Tags: tensorflow

I'm kind of a newbie in Tensorflow (and also Theano). I have been exploring, this week, several ideas with Tensorflow and, yesterday, I found out about control flow and the scan function. I also took a look at the Theano scan method and I notice some important: Theano supports temporal taps, Tensorflow does not.

Is there a design pattern to implement temporal taps for -2, -3, -4, etc, in Tensorflow?